# Create a new Range object in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I need to replace the text in a Word citation. Since the citations are read-only, I need to delete an old citations and create a new one after that:

```
        Set r = fld.Result
        s = fld.Code.Text
        fld.Cut
        r.Fields.Add r, wdFieldCitation, s, False
```

The problem is that I cannot edit the text in `r` (or `fld.Result`), therefore I need to create a new `Range` variable with new text, but I haven't found any ways to do that. How can I create an edible clone of a given `Range` variable in VBA?

UPD: 
Here's the broken code I wrote to replace citation fields

```
Sub UpdateCitations()
    Dim fld As Field
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Range
    For Each fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If fld.Type = wdFieldCitation Then
            If fld.Result.Text = "[Please use macros to update citations]" Then
                Dim citationId As Integer
                citationId = FindCitationIndex(Split(fld.Code.Text, " ")(2))
                Set r = fld.Result
                ' Here I need to edit the r.Text variable, but I get error 6124,
                ' because fld.Result.Text is read-only in citaion fields
                ' r.Text = "Citation changed"
                s = fld.Code.Text
                fld.Cut
                r.Fields.Add r, wdFieldCitation, s, False
           End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function FindCitationIndex(ByVal tag As String) As Integer
    Dim src As Source
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 1
    For Each src In ActiveDocument.Bibliography.Sources
        If src.tag = tag Then
            FindCitationIndex = counter
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Next
End Function
```

**UPD2**

My task is to create a macro or a bibliography style which will can be sorted either alhabetically or by the reference order. The citations should be numerical.

I have managed to create a bibliography style that will sort the sources in the way I need, but I couldn't retrieve the index of a source in the bibliography in XSLT, so I've decided to put a message `[Please use a macro to update citations]` and later replace this message with an actual index with a macro, but I couldn't neither edit nor create new citation fields.
I run Office 2010.

Comment: I'd love to help you but can you please add more context to your question. It's hard to understand what is going here in your code. What is `r?` what is `fld` i mean what data types. Please add more info

Comment: @mehow I've added the code I wrote. `r` is a `Range` object and `fld` is a `Field`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mehow, there are some important information missing. But try with this changed last line of your code:

```
r.Fields.Add r, , s, False
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it didn't solve my problem. I've added the code I've written, maybe it will help.

Comment: all variables-`r, fld` are exactly the same which I assumed and it's working fine for me. What error/unexpected behaviour you get? Which version of Office you run?

Comment: one more thing- I tried to do replacement for all fields which doesn't go for me with `For each loop`. I had to use `For i=Activedocument.Fields.count to 1 step -1` to catch all fields!!

Comment: I've added a line where I try to modify the text in the citation field, that's where I get an error.

Comment: you didn't answer the question about office version you run?

Comment: do I get you right that you get an error for `r.Text = "Citation changed"`- that is correct and this is why you try to cut and paste new field. So, where is the real problem now? have you tried to replace your `r.Fields.Add r, wdFieldCitation, s, False` with my code? what error you get or what is going wrong, please describe and add some screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the style you wish at the quick styles of word, and them programatically apply it to your citations using the command:

```
Sub FormatSelection()
    Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
        Set wordDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(MSWordPath) 'Replace it with the File Path
         'The Selection could be made by the command wordDoc.Paragraphs(PositionReference).Range.Select or by any other select method
        With objword.Selection
            .Style = SourceDoc.Styles(ItemHeaderStyle)'Style you've created for this purpose
        End with
End Sub
```